# Ruby in HTML button-method

Tags: html, ruby, button

I want to use a button inside HTML using information from the HTML itself.

More in detail:

There is a html.erb file. In there lay 2 `<input type="hidden" name="Name" value='Tom'>` and a Button.

Within the html.erb file i could get the value by typing `params['Name']`. But here comes my Problem. I have no idea how to write a button, so that it will only save @user when i click it. Therefore the method of the button should be something like:

```
@user.name = params["Name"]
@user.age = params["Age"]
@user.save
```

For me it looks like the simplest if i had this method(of the button) within the html, where `@user`, the name and the age are stored. But i'm a new to ruby, so what do i know.

Comment: Please see example of button_to from http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/button_to

Comment: I'm assuming this is in a Rails view? If so then the params hash is only available in the controller, and you will need to set those values to instance variables in order for them to be available in the view.

Answer (score 0):

In your controller where you have access to the `params['Name']` and `params['Age']` to save or update an existing one:

```
@user.name = params["Name"]
@user.age = params["Age"]
@user.save
```

A more Rails-y way, however is to use `form_for` to create a form for an object:

```
# show.html.erb (or whatever controller action the view is for)
<% form_for @user do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :name %>
  <%= f.text_field :age %>
  <%= button_to "Save User" %>
<% end %> 

# user_controller.rb
# If creating:
@user = User.new(params[:user])
# or for updating: (no need for save)
# @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
@user.save
```

Since the `:age` and `:name` will be passed in the `:user` hash looking like this:

```
user: { 
  name: "John",
  age: 18
}
```

which can be passed to `User.new` or `@user.update_attributes` and it will set `@user.name` and `@user.age` from the hash.

I suggest browsing the [saving data in the controller](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#saving-data-in-the-controller) section of the Rails guides

Comment: I think you got the wrong idea.
`@user` is the instance of the userclass needed in this html.
`@name` doesn't exist only `@user.name`

The Button Name is "Save User" the function of the button is:
`@user.name=params['Name']`
`@user.age=params['Age']`
That would save the name and age right?!

Comment: I see, no you'd have to do that in the `UserController`, you cannot do that from the view

Comment: Sadly i don't have access to the `params['Name']` and `params['Age']` in the Controller.

Comment: print out `params` or use a debugger/`binding.pry` to see what's in the `params` variable. You may have to permit parameters, try `params.require(:user).permit(:name, :age)` if using `form_for`